# Hibernate: how to extract the time part

Tags: java, database, hibernate

just want to insert the time part in data base using hibernate ....

what i am trying is .....

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    UserID ui = new UserID();
    CompKeyClass ckc1=new CompKeyClass();
    ckc1.setAge(21);
    ckc1.setUserID(ui);
    ui.setDeptno("1002");
    ckc1.setCal1(cal.getTime());
            ......

@Id
private UserID userID;
@SequenceGenerator(name="myseqgen",sequenceName="employeehib")
@GeneratedValue(generator="myseqgen")
private char man='a';
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date hireDate;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date timedate;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date datedate;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date cal1;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
```

but here when i am  calling the getTime method its showing the date .

is there any way to show only the time part....

Comment: Unrelated to the concrete question. Use the [Joda-time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) in the future. You will never have  to scratch your head while handling data time related tasks. Integrating this API with Hibernate/JPA requires a bit Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Or

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String time = dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
```